# Why do annotation parameters not use a comma as separator?

Tags: apex, invocable-method, parameters, annotations

Looking at the official documentation for the annotation `InvocableMethod` we can see that the parameters - unlike other languages I know - do not use a comma as a separator for the parameters.

Any insights on why that is? Are there other languages that only use a space as a separator?

`@InvocableMethod(label='Get Account Names' description='Returns the list of account names corresponding to the specified account IDs.' category='Account')`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

Comment: xml attributes are like this.

Comment: @CasparHarmer That's not really the same thing. XML is typically data, not code.

Comment: There are about a dozen xml based programming languages. Probably the best known is XSLT, which is Turing Complete.

Comment: Also, annotations are code metadata, which is blurring the line between code and data.

Comment: Aren't annotations just functions? At least in other languages? I've done so much Apex that I honestly forgot.